# Update metadata to add existing file to Delta Lake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I have many small JSON files and am hoping to aggregate them into larger Parquet files using AWS Athena, write the output to the S3 folder where the Delta Table is stored, and then append the data to Delta Lake. I am hoping to update the metadata without rewriting the data itself similarly to how convertToDelta() does an in-place conversion.

```
DeltaTable.convertToDelta(spark, uri)
```

```
# Functionality I want:
DeltaTable.addFile(spark, file_uri) # Does not rewrite datafile, only updates metadata
```

I have been successful using Delta Standalone; however, I want to avoid adding additional technologies to the mix if possible. Is there any way this can be done?

Update:
Due to the fact that that all methods of appending mentioned in the docs appear to involve rewriting data, it appears that this may not be possible using only the Spark implementation of Delta Lake.

Comment: Why not just aggregate JSON into Delta directly by Spark?

Comment: I have many small files that are slow and costly to read. Athena is cheap and fast for aggregation, but I would like to further optimize to avoid data duplication.